# CompletableFuture onTimeout get the supplied value java async programming

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-9, completable-future

I have a completablefuture chain to which a pass a parameter (object) and each step of the chain is doing some work.
i have some slow steps which i want to limit with a timeout

what i noticed that indeed the timeout exception is thrown but i have no idea on which parameter

```
ComplianceCandidate candidate = candidates.poll();
            CompletableFuture<ComplianceCandidate> futureTask = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> candidate, pool)
                    .thenApply(Task1::doWork).thenApply(Task2::doWork).thenApply(Task3::doWork)
                    .thenApply(Task4::doWork).thenApply(ProblematicAndSlowTask::doWork).thenApply(AnotherProblematicTask::doWork)
                    .thenApply(Task6::doWork).thenApply(Task7::doWork).orTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .exceptionally(ExceptionHandlerService::handle);
            completedList.add(futureTask);
```

is there a way in the completable future api to obtain the parameter passed to the doWork method that has failed?

Comment: It’s always `Task7::doWork`, as that’s the only operation you are applying a timeout to. All other futures are entirely unaffected.

Comment: The timeout is for the chain not an individual task

Comment: That’s perhaps what you *want*, but not what happens. Calling `orTimeOut` on a future will create a timeout for that single future only.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible because, as Holger explained in the comments, `orTimeout()` applies only to the `CompletableFuture` you call it on. There is no reference to the call chain (or, in fact, graph) that leads to that future.

You can, however, inspect all intermediate `CompletableFuture`s by storing their references:

```
CompletableFuture<ComplianceCandidate> init = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> candidate, pool);
CompletableFuture<Result1> future1 = init.thenApply(Task1::doWork);
CompletableFuture<Result2> future2 = future1.thenApply(Task2::doWork);
…
CompletableFuture<Result7> future7 = future6.thenApply(Task7::doWork);
CompletionStage<Result7> future7OrTimeout = future7.orTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and then check each of them individually:

```
CompletableFuture<ComplianceCandidate> futureTask = future7OrTimeout.exceptionally(throwable -> {
    if (!future1.isDone() || future1.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
        System.out.println("Task1 failed");
    } else if (!future2.isDone() || future2.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
        System.out.println("Task2 failed")
    } else …
});
```

(I let it up to you to make the code more generic with loops depending on what your actual calls are)